# Not adding a slash if 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I test my 404 with URL : domain.com/fff

In my log I see :

```
"HEAD /fff HTTP/1.1" 301 299 "-" 
"HEAD /fff/ HTTP/1.1" 302 451 "-"
"HEAD /404 HTTP/1.1" 301 299 "-" 
"HEAD /404/ HTTP/1.1" 404 356 "-"
```

Rules in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^missing$ missing.html [END]
ErrorDocument 401 /missing
ErrorDocument 403 /missing
ErrorDocument 404 /missing
ErrorDocument 406 /missing
ErrorDocument 500 /missing
ErrorDocument 503 /missing

# I want to avoid adding slash if status is 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|css|woff|ico|404|js|xml|jpg|png|gif|svg|mp3|ogg)$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=404
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

I tried  `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=404`but it doesn't work (see the log above) any idea?

Comment: no it isn't, the htaccess added the slash at the end because of the RewriteCond even if I used the ENV: REDIRECT_STATUS to avoid this situation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved:

I was redirecting to domain.com/404 if I was unable to find the content.
So I added this to my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=404
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^404$
```

Now it is working :)
Thanks